# Divs always need to adjust margin-top property

Tags: jquery, css, html

I have a div container which contains 3 divs which is subdivided into ff: left column, right column and a footer,

so basically things should look like these;

```
-------------------------------
'       '                     '
'       '                     '
'       '                     '
'       '                     '
'       '                     '
'       '                     '
'       '                     '
'       '                     '
'       '                     '
-------------------------------
'                             '
'                             '
-------------------------------
```

The left and right column are dynamically populated with info that's coming from a database; meaning each div's (left/right) can take up small or large area of the page;

But in my case, I'm having a unexpected behavior, the right div seems to start almost below the left div, as in;

```
---------
'       '                     
'       '                     
'       '                     
'       -----------------------                     '
'       '                     '
--------'                     '
        '                     '
        '                     '
        '                     '
        '                     '
        -----------------------
```

So it means when I want the right div to be like the left div's top, I have to re-adjust all the time, but that is not what I want to do, I want the left and right div's top the same all the time... below is the source I have for both, can somebody help with do this with jsfiddle to see the exact result quickly?

```
div#divLeft
{
background-color: green;
/*height: 100%;*/
width: 25%;
float: left;
}

div#divRight
{
background-color: red;
width: 73%;
position: relative;
margin-top: -52px;
margin-left: 25%;
float: left;
}
```

here's a jsfiddle thing; http://jsfiddle.net/Rqyz7/ -> hope it works, I think I have some problems with the net right now... TIA

Comment: You don't need to position: absolute your container div. And you can get rid of the position: relative on the #divRight and I would get right of the margin-top and margin-left on #divRight and they should line up

Comment: You could try putting them into one div with a fixed width thats larger than both dynamically loaded divs side by side

Answer (score 0):

Updated Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/nupul/Rqyz7/7/

Basically when you add a margin to the right div you are increasing it's width by "more than 75% in total" i.e. `width:73%` and `margin-left:25%` - This makes the div's width greater than the allowable 
75% (since divLeft is 25%). Either fix the margin, drop it or be more precise with the numbers.

Second: The footer needs to have it's floats cleared so as to flow "after" the right div but at the bottom of left and right divs.

Comment: But have you noticed the divRight items doesn't appear to be complete?

Answer (score 0):

Basically, the second column is trying to put some margin between the first, and doesn't fit, going to a new row.
There are two ways, and the problem is you're doing both. You either:

- Give both columns `float: left`, and the container `overflow: auto`, to let the container grow to the tallest of the two, and therefore keep the footer from overlapping them.
- Give the first `float: left`, and the second one a `margin-left`. This way the footer will come after the second column, regardless of the height of the first. Use this when the first column is never taller than the second.

You either remove the margin-left, or the float from the second div, depending on the growing behavior you want for the columns.

Comment: I wouldn't use an empty div with a "clear: both". I would just give an "overflow: auto" to the div that contains the two floated elements.

Comment: You're right, that's better, I was thinking too old-school. I updated my answer, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Give both the `div` columns style attributes `display:inline-block;` and `vertical-align:top;`, and remove any `float` and `margin` attributes. This will display both inline while allowing you to define the vertical align as the top.

JSFiddle sample [here](http://jsfiddle.net/uWXTd/) and sample with larger column [here](http://jsfiddle.net/uWXTd/1/)